# How to override Enter press on a button in xamarin pcl UWP?

Tags: button, xamarin, uwp, renderer, xamarin.uwp

Hy,

I'm working on a xamarin PCL project with a lot of entries and buttons for UWP. For the entries I have iplemented in a custom renderer a keydown and keyup function for detecting the Enter press. As result it goes to the next UI element.
For a button I need the same detection but in the renderer in doesn't goes to the function keyup or keydown.

So How can I make a button detect an Enter press before executing the original command?

Here is the code that I've implemented.

```cs
public class CustomButtonRenderer : ButtonRenderer
{
    public CustomButtonRenderer()
    {
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.Button> e)
    {
        Xamarin.Forms.Button appButton = (Xamarin.Forms.Button)Element;
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (Control != null && appButton != null)
        {
            Control.KeyUp += Control_KeyUp;
            Control.KeyDown += Control_KeyDown;
        }
    }


    private void Control_KeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
    }
    private void Control_KeyUp(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Xamarin.Forms.Button appButton = (Xamarin.Forms.Button)Element;
        switch (e.Key)
        {
            case (Windows.System.VirtualKey.Enter):
                {
                    FocusManager.TryMoveFocus(FocusNavigationDirection.Next);
                    break;
                }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the [KeyRoutedEventArgs.Handled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.input.keyroutedeventargs#Windows_UI_Xaml_Input_KeyRoutedEventArgs_Handled) property to `true`. This should do what you asked:

```cs
private void Control_KeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Enter)
    {
        FocusManager.TryMoveFocus(FocusNavigationDirection.Next);
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the Control_keyDown isn't called when I press Enter or Space. Every other key it goes to the method but not with this 2 keys.

Comment: Only in the function Control_click it goes. But than I can't see with key is pressed.